# How do HttpSession and HttpServletRequest inject into Spring by @Autowired?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, dependency-injection

There are many Dependency Injection (DI) methods such as declare bean in XML, @annotation, setter or constructor.. etc.
The `HttpSession` without any DI method like above, how does it inject into Spring context?
I saw lots of codes that inject `HttpSession` or Request directly by `@Autowired` like below:

```
@Controller
public class MyController{

@Autowired
private HttpSession session;

@RequestMapping("/hello")
    return "hello world";
}
```

---

I can't understand how does the `HttpSession` inject into the controller without any bean injected into `context.xml` or annotated by `@Component`.

Can anyone give me the detail of the reason or link about that?

A: method "registerWebApplicationScopes" in WebApplicationContextUtils.java registers such HttpRequest by ConfigurableListableBeanFactory. Also, the method findAutowiredCandicate in DefaultListableBeanFactory shows how does such beans inject into spring context.

Comment: @Sotirios Delimanolis It's not the same question. I've googled a lot but can not find one the solve my  confusion thus I post it.

Comment: Can you explain what you think is missing from the accepted answer? It explains in detail how a `HttpServletRequest` can be injected. The behavior is the same for `HttpSession`.